# How do you calculate the area of a 2D polygon in 3D?

Tags: 3d, polygons

How can I calculate the surface area of a set of coplanar points, representing the vertices of a polygon, in three dimensions?

Should I convert it into 2D, or is there a way to compute this quantity in 3D?

Comment: Are the vertices coplanar ?

Comment: @JeanMarie yes, they are

Comment: Let's say your vertices are $\vec{v}_1,  \vec{v}_2, \ldots, \vec{v}_n$. Let $\vec{v}_0 = \vec{v}_n$. Compute the sum of cross products
$$\vec{A} = \frac12 \sum_{k=1}^n \vec{v}_k \times \vec{v}_{k-1}$$
If the vertices are coplanar, then it has area $|\vec{A}|$

Comment: @achille hui One has to be careful : vertices $A_k$  can be coplanar without the $v_k=\vec{OA_k}$ being so. Thus taking the norm at the end instead of taking it every time will not work. Example with $A_1(1,1,1),A_2(1,-1,1),A_3(-1,-1,1),A_4(-1,1,1)$.

Comment: @JeanMarie the formula doesn't assume $\vec{v}_k = \vec{OA}_k$ to be coplanar. If you replace $\vec{v}_k$ by $\vec{PA}_k$ for any reference point $P$, the $P$ dependent part of the sum cancel out. In fact, you should not take the norm before the sum. The formula for sum of individual area can fail if the reference point is outside the polygon or when the polygon is non-convex.

Comment: @achille hui I understand. I see also that I had assumed implicitly that the polygon is convex. Thanks.

Comment: @achillehui There might be a problem, when the polygonal chain defined by the sequence of points intersects itself, e.g. like a pentagram. But for simple polygons the formula should work fine despite the polygon being convex or concave.

Comment: @CiaPan self-crossing polygons have of course to be avoided, first of all because there is no "natural" definition of their area.

Comment: @CiaPan when the polygon chain self intersect, $|\vec{A}|$ no longer gives you the area of the region bounded by the chain. Instead, it equals to the absolute value of the sum of area of the sub-regions weighted by winding numbers.

Comment: @achillehui That's why I said it makes a problem. But the most important is _convexity does not matter_ (as long as it doesn't lead to self-intersections).

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to come back to a 2D framework.

Let $O=\dfrac1n \sum A_k$ be the center of gravity of your cloud of points. It belongs naturally to their common plane.

The area of triangle $OA_kA_{k+1}$ is

$$\dfrac12\|\vec{OA_k} \times \vec{OA_{k+1}}\|$$

(half the norm of the cross product : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product).

But, after discussion with @achille hui (that I thank very much for this remark), sum all these vectors and take their norm at the end.

$$area =\left\| \sum_{k=1}^{k=n}\dfrac12\vec{OA_k} \times \vec{OA_{k+1}} \right\| \tag{1}$$

(we assume cyclicity, i.e., $A_{n+1}=A_1$)

The benefit of taking norm at the end instead of taking it each time is that you can cope in this way with non-convex polygons.

Remark : A simpler formula : instead of taking the center of gravity $O$, one can take for example $A_1$ as the reference point. In this case, the two terms containing $\vec{OA_1}$ vanish, transforming the sum with $n+1$ terms into the following sum containing $n-1$ terms only:

$$area =\left\| \sum_{k=2}^{k=n-1} \dfrac12\vec{A_1A_k} \times \vec{A_1A_{k+1}} \right\| \tag{2}$$

Explanation : Let $\vec{N}$ be a normal unit vector to the plane of the $A_k$. Let us assume first that the set of vertices $A_k$ is convex. When "traversing" it, we will have

$$\dfrac12\vec{OA_k} \times \vec{OA_{k+1}}=a_k\vec{N}$$

with $a_k$ the signed area of triangle $OA_kA_{k+1}$

If we assumed that $\vec{N}$ is oriented such that all $a_k \geq 0$, this explains the result. But the "miracle" is that, if the polygon generated by the $A_k$ isn't convex, some of the $a_k$s will become negative, but it will not entail the result because there willl be areas concellations.

**Edit:** Formula (2) can be extended not only to non-convex polygons but as well to certain self-crossing polygons. For example in the following case, formula (2) gives the following sum $2-3+2=1$ which is equal to the sum $+2-1=-1$ of **oriented** areas of the upper square (area $+2$) and area of right triangle at the bottom which is $-1$.

In fact all this is well descibed under the "shoelace formula" terminology [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula).

[image]

Comment: In fact the choice of the reference point doesn't matter, so one can simply use the origin as in achille hui's comment. That said, your choices probably gives better numerical stability.

Comment: @Rahul : after an exchange with achille hui, you and him are perfectly right : $O$ doesn't need to belong to the same plane as the vertices.

Comment: $O=A_1$ would work as well.

Comment: @CiaPan It is what I have given as a remark. Taking at first another origin has only a pedagogical interest.

Comment: Yup, Didn't read the whole answer carefully enough. There is a practical distinction in selecting the reference point. If one works with geodesic or geographic data, the origin of the coordinate system may be far from the area of interest. Choosing a local point reduces number of significant digits one needs to maintain for any chosen precison of the result. And by choosing one of vertices instead of any mean point one avoids introducing unnecessary errors into calculations.

Comment: @CiaPan Thoughtful remark. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "cyclicity" here? That the points should be ordered as if they are going around the polygonal shape?

Comment: @Connor I mean by 'cyclicity" a technical point in indexation : if for example there are 5 points, $A_1, \cdots A_5$, we will need to say that $A_6$ is the same as $A_1$ in order to close the loop more easily...,

Comment: @JeanMarie I see, so the points have to follow some sort of circular order, as if they were consecutive points on a circle or something like that?

Comment: @Connor : see the edit I just added.